# Best place to load caption strings in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, localization, internationalization

Where is the best place to load caption strings in a MFC application?

I'm loading control captions in the **OnInitialUpdate** method of my views and loading menu items captions in the **OnCreate** method of my frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe there are more than 100 of captions in your program. You can load them in `InitInstance` itself - no harm.

If there are more than few hundreds of captions to load, it would take the GUI to appear (irrespective of where you load, since GUI/total thread is one). In that case, you should load all important resources/captions while startup (in `InitInstance`), and defer/delegate the loading of other captions to other thread/later-time.

Comment: Is OnInitialUpdate better or worse than InitInstance? What's the difference between each aproach?

Comment: It won't matter much. But when you change the application to something else, which will not have CView or Doc/View, `OnInitialUpdate` method will not be called. Therefore, it may be better to consider InitInstance.

Answer (score 2):

What does not work with your current approach? Why do you want to load them somewhere else? In general, the best place to load them is when you need them (I'm assuming you're talking about loading strings from the resource section with CString::LoadString() ).

Comment: Yes, I'm loading them with CString::LoadString() from a resource file. I'm just wondering if I'm loading them in the right place or there's a more apropriate place.

Answer (score 2):

If the menu and other controls are part of a dialog then, [`OnInitDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwz35s59%28VS.80%29.aspx) is a good place to set the captions for the dialog and its controls.